# Load image without autoscaling in Android

Tags: android, image, resize, bufferedimage

I'm trying to create a map for a game through an image, where each black pixel is equivalent to a wall, and yellow to flowers(1) and green grass(0)
so far i had this image (50x50):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTANP.png

the problem here seems to be that, when i read the image on my code, it get's scaled up to 100x100, even tough i have it on the raw folder. I can't let it scale up or down because that will put noise and blur on the image and then the map won't be readable.

here i have my code:

```
(...)
Bitmap tab=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, com.example.lolitos2.R.raw.mappixel);
    //tab=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tab, 50, 50, false);
    Log.e("w", tab.getWidth()+"."+tab.getHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tab.getHeight(); j++) {
            int x = j;
            int y = i;
            switch (tab.getPixel(x, y)) {
            // se o é uma parede
            case Color.BLACK:
                getParedes()[x][y] = new Parede(x, y);
                break;
            case Color.GREEN:
                fundo.add(new Passivo(x,y,0));
                break;
            default:
                fundo.add(new Passivo(x,y,1));
            }

        }
    }
```

How can i read my image Map without rescaling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them in the `drawable-nodpi` folder, instead of in `raw`, then just read them as any other `BitmapDrawable`.

> If you have some drawable resources that the system should never scale
>   (perhaps because you perform some adjustments to the image yourself at
>   runtime), you should place them in a directory with the nodpi
>   configuration qualifier. Resources with this qualifier are considered
>   density-agnostic and the system will not scale them.

(From http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

(If necessary, there are other ways, e.g. you can provide an `inDensity` parameter to the options of `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`).

Comment: @Mira glad to have helped :)

Answer (score -2):

Problem is at  following line

tab=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tab, 50, 50, false);

Change those 50s to larger number.

Hit like if I helped you
Thanks

Comment: did you read the OP? They want to create a bitmap at exactly 50x50. I don't see how "changing those 50s to larger numbers" will help

Comment: Well then, I am pretty sure you haven't been to android site.  Check out this link. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: @DushyantPatel can you point out on that page what the OP is supposed to be looking at?