# Android - Bitmap Interpolation?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to render some pixel art on a Bitmap on a canvas.

What I want it to look like:

http://puu.sh/9e8Ig/0cc6663b6c.png

What it is rendering like:

http://puu.sh/9e8JR/9ec821d9f8.png

This is the code for when they're defined:

```
Bitmap gameovertitle;

gameovertitle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.pnggameovertext);
gameovertitle = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(gameovertitle, CanvasWidth, (int) (CanvasWidth / 2.48), **false**);
```

Code for where it's drawn:
    c.drawBitmap(menuplaybuttons, 0, 0, null);

Does anyone know how to fix this? :/
I believe the problem has to do with the interpolation.

I've searched tons of different posts but cant seem to find any helpful information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Thanks,
Jason*

Comment: have you tried putting your gameovertext png in the drawable-nodpi folder instead of raw?

Comment: What @panini said. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006461/load-image-without-autoscaling-in-android/). Android will autoscale images unless they match the screen density. Putting them in the drawable-nodpi disables that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Canvas and a Bitmap as its output

Then draw the bitmaps one by one on the resultant Bitmap